# How to group array and count values

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have an array that I want to group according to type then count the number of instances for every unique status.

Here is my array:

```
  const array =   [
      { type: 'A', number: 2, status:'Approved', year: '2020' },
      { type: 'A', number: 3, status:'Approved', year: '2020' },
      { type: 'A', number: 3, status:'Disapproved', year: '2020' },
      { type: 'A', number: 6, status:'Disapproved', year: '2020' },
      { type: 'A', number: 5, status:'Processing', year: '2020' },
      { type: 'B', number: 8, status:'Processing', year: '2020' },
      { type: 'B', number: 2, status:'Approved', year: '2020' },
      { type: 'B', number: 2, status:'Disapproved', year: '2020' },
      ]
```

Here is my desired array:

```
  const desiredArray =   [
    { type: 'A',  Approved:5, Disapproved: 9, Processing: 13, year: '2020' },
    { type: 'B',  Approved:2, Disapproved: 2, year: '2020' },
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

With help from other online friends, this worked perfectly:

```
  const reducedObject = array.reduce((rv,x) =>{
    if(!rv[x.type]) {
      rv[x.type] = {
        type: x.type,
        Approved: 0, 
        Disapproved: 0, 
        Processing: 0, 
        year: x.year
      }
    }

    rv[x.type][x.status]++;
    return rv;
  }, {});
  
  const desiredArray = Object.values(reducedObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

```
var array = [
  { Id: "001", qty: 1 }, 
  { Id: "002", qty: 2 }, 
  { Id: "001", qty: 2 }, 
  { Id: "003", qty: 4 }
];

var result = [];
array.reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.Id]) {
    res[value.Id] = { Id: value.Id, qty: 0 };
    result.push(res[value.Id])
  }
  res[value.Id].qty += value.qty;
  return res;
}, {});
```

console.log(result)